# a class that is in my namespace is getting an error that it is not in my namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have two almost identical converters one of which is getting an error in my XAML that it does not exist in the namespace when it obviously does.
I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. Opening and closing visual studio. rebooting. deleting and re-creating the class with the issue. manually retyping the class instead of copying and pasting it. verified my XAML has no errors. verified the class has no errors. I'm still getting the error that it is not in the namespace. Any help would be wonderful

my code:

```
namespace ScoreBoardClientTest
{
    class LunchRangeToBooleanConverterTime : IValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly TimeSpan _toCompare = new TimeSpan(00, 60, 00);

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is TimeSpan))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return (TimeSpan)value > _toCompare;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("To Long On Lunch");
        }      
    }
}
```

my XAML where the error exists. Error is in LunchRangeToBooleanConverterTime

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
 <local:BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime x:Key="breakconvtime"/>                
 <local:LunchRangeToBooleanConverterTime x:Key="lunchconvtime"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

the almost identical first class that I was asked to share. This one I have no problems with at all:

```
namespace ScoreBoardClientTest
{
    class BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime : IValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly TimeSpan _toCompare = new TimeSpan(00, 15, 00);
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is TimeSpan))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return (TimeSpan)value > _toCompare;
        }      

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("To Long On Break");
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `local` namespace at the top of your XAML page? I'm talking about

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScoreBoardClientTest;assembly={CheckYourScoreBoardClientTestAssembly (Can be found on your Project Properties)}
```

Add this as a property in your page/window tag, in order to use your classes.

Comment: This is confusing to me because the first class for break works just fine. I do have the xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScoreBoardClientTest" at the top of the XAML already but I don't have an assembly. I've never had to add an assembly reference previously. I mean I'll try it, I just don't understand why.

Comment: so I'm looking in my assembly and all I see if an assembly: ComVisible(false) and an assembly GUID

Comment: Can you also share the first class? Thanks!

Comment: added the working class. let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but can you try changing both of classes' access modifiers to `public`?

Comment: just did that. made no difference.

Comment: so i just made the variable declaration at the top public also on both of them and now neither one of them are in the namespace...changing everything back to private

Comment: ... so three cleans and builds later I changed everything back to private that I just changed to public and the issue is gone...can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Wow. That's confusing

Comment: yes but I'm afraid to build it again. the issue might re-occur.  lol

Comment: guess I'll give you resolution credit lol. given its working and your the only one to help. Thank you. have a good night!

Comment: Thanks! Hahaha. Good luck with your project! :)